# Install Mercurial 1.9.1 (isapi) on win2k3

Tags: python, version-control, mercurial

I have been trying to get Mercurial installed on my 32bit 2003 server and i have been running into some issues. i have followed [these instructions](http://www.eworldui.net/blog/post/2010/04/08/Setting-up-Mercurial-server-in-IIS7-using-a-ISAPI-module.aspx) (which is the most current that i can find) with the exception i used the following versions that differ.

- python 2.6.6
- mercurial 1.9.1

  - mercurial 1.9 (no change/ same error)
  - mercurial 1.8.1 (no change/ same error)

After the install everything appears to be ok but then i get this error in eventvwr when i hit the site.

> **Failed to import callback module 'hgwebdir_wsgi'**

I'm not sure where to start with this one, i have tried [this](http://selenic.com/pipermail/mercurial/2011-January/036596.html) but it didnt seem to make any change.  I even tried this twice once as an over install/upgrade and once as a clean install.

Answer (score 1):

I recently did the same as you on Windows Server 2008 with the same result when I used Mercurial 1.9.1. However, switching to an older version of Mercurial worked for me (I'm not 100% on the version number but I think it was 1.8.1)

Did you download the 1.8.1 version of hgwebdir_wsgi.py and regenerate the dll when you installed the older version of Mercurial?

Other possible issues:
  Did you remember to enable 32 bit extensions in IIS?
  Is python in your path? Can you execute it from a cmd prompt from any folder?

Edit:
I followed [these](http://www.firegarden.com/software/hosting-mercurial-repo-iis7-windows-server-2008r2-x64-python-isapi-cgi) instructions and they are the ones that didn't work for 1.9 and did work for 1.8.1.  Comparing them to the instructions that you followed I can see one step which is different:  it says to download the source for mercurial and to compile it (your reference page refers to  using the source installation but not to compiling it)

Comment: I did download and try the 3 versions above, 1.9.1, 1.9, and 1.8.1 each time i would regen the dll with the *new* version of hgwebdir_wsgi.py.  At this time i have HG running and but not with the asapi module.

Comment: I've added a reference to the page that I followed.  It does have some differences.

Comment: thanks, i will check this out when the next version comes out.  i'm tired of messing with it for now.  when i do get this running i will update this post.